# Scala Databricks: read a JSON file and return two DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code :

```
def reader (path:String):DataFrame={

val path =sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/Data_exo2.json").reduce((a,b)=>s"$a$b")

val df = Seq((path)).toDF()

val schema_tran = new StructType()
.add("Devis", StringType, false)
.add("IdTransaction",LongType, false)
.add("Pays", StringType, false)
.add("Prix",DoubleType, false)   
.add("TypeProduit", StringType, false)

val schema = new StructType().add("Transaction", ArrayType(schema_tran),true)
                      
val df_66 = df.select(from_json($"value",schema)as "struct")
.select($"struct.*")
.withColumn("Transaction", explode(col("Transaction")))
.select($"Transaction.*")



val schema_devis = new StructType()
                                    
.add("Devis", StringType, false)
.add("Taux",DoubleType, false) 

val schema_1 = new StructType()
.add("Devis", ArrayType(schema_devis),true)

val df_67 = df.select(from_json($"value",schema_1)as "struct")
.select($"struct.*")
.withColumn("Devis", explode(col("Devis")))
.select($"Devis.*")
 *****}
```

So I have two dataframe df_66 and df_67.
Basicaly, I want to define a fonction to return those dataframe, one by one like this reader(path)(0)

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Wrap the code in a function and return a list containing the two

Comment: you mean, I just need to add at the end " return(df_66,df_67) "? if it's this I tried it but it doesnt work

Comment: No. That is a `tuple`. Please go through a basic Scala tutorial before diving into Spark. There are numerous free resources including some on the Scala website. It will give you the necessary background you need on how to define function, how to create lists and more. We can not help you when you clearly haven't put in any effort to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: I will (it was in my plan) and thank you for your advice ^^, but I just want to know how to return two dataframe that's it. I'm not Scala user indeed and I have to make more "Effort" as you said, but it's just urgent matter that's it ^^ but thank anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
def reader(path: String): Map[Int, DataFrame] = {
    
    val df = spark.read.format("json").load(path)

    val schema_tran = new StructType()
    .add("Devis", StringType, false)
    .add("IdTransaction",LongType, false)
    .add("Pays", StringType, false)
    .add("Prix",DoubleType, false)   
    .add("TypeProduit", StringType, false)

    val schema = new StructType().add("Transaction", ArrayType(schema_tran),true)
                        
    val df_66 = df.select(from_json($"value",schema)as "struct")
    .select($"struct.*")
    .withColumn("Transaction", explode(col("Transaction")))
    .select($"Transaction.*")


    val schema_devis = new StructType()
                                        
    .add("Devis", StringType, false)
    .add("Taux",DoubleType, false) 

    val schema_1 = new StructType()
    .add("Devis", ArrayType(schema_devis),true)

    val df_67 = df.select(from_json($"value",schema_1)as "struct")
    .select($"struct.*")
    .withColumn("Devis", explode(col("Devis")))
    .select($"Devis.*")

    Map(
        0 -> df_66,
        1 -> df_67
    )
}
```

You can get the DataFrame back using

```
reader("some path")(0) // df_66
reader("some path")(1) // df_67
```

Comment: yes I was looking for this, thank you very much